# Showing commutativity of stalks and kernels explicitly

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometry, algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

This comes from exercise II.1.2(a) from Hartshorne. I am stuck with trying to show the inclusion $ker(\phi_{p}) \subseteq ker(\phi)_{p}$ where we have the morphism of sheaves given by $$\phi: \mathcal{F} \to \mathcal{G}$$ I understand that by definition the stalk is given by equivalence classes of pairs $<U,s>$, where $U \ni p$ is an open neighborhood of the topological space $X$, and $s$ is a section in $\mathcal{F}(U)$.

How should I prove the above inclusion? Does it not easily follow that the existence of a pair $<U,s> \in \ker(\phi_{p}) \subseteq \mathcal{F}_{p}$ imply that we can find an open neighborhood $U \ni x$ and the section $s \in \mathcal{F}(U)$ such that it vanishes on $\phi(U)$?

In particular, I have been looking at the solution given here: http://www.math.utah.edu/~zwick/Classes/Hartshorne/Section2_1.pdf

I don't understand the statement $s|p = s_{p}$. Isn't $s_{p} \in \mathcal{F}_{p}$ an ordered pair while $s|p$ is the restriction of the section to a single point? And I also don't understand why that implies the second statement and the existence of the equation on an open set when the equality only holds at a single point $p$.

Edit: I guess the main thing that I'm not solid on is what exactly the notion of the germ $s_{p}$, i.e. the image of the section $s$ in $F_{p}$. Is it simply fixing the above pair $<U,s>$ to a single section $s_{o}$, whilst keeping the same equivalence relations, which is just the notation $s|p$, along with the associated open set?

Comment: I guess they've invented some notation. I'm afraid that I can't really follow your last paragraph. I don't think they're saying anything more than the definition of $\mathcal{F}_P$: if you pick some $\alpha \in \mathcal{F}_P$ then it has this form $\alpha = \langle U, s\rangle$. The $s|_P$ notation is not something I've seen anyone use before. What you should know is that for any neighborhood $U$ of $P$ there is a natural homomorphism $\mathcal{F}(U) \to \mathcal{F}_P$.

Comment: Anyway, the logic you want to trace through is this: if I have $\langle U, s\rangle$ in $\ker \varphi_P$ then the definitions say that $\langle U, \varphi(U)(s)\rangle$ is zero as an element of $\mathcal{G}_P$. Using the definition of $\mathcal{G}_P$, what does _that_ mean? You really need to use that $\varphi$ is a morphism of sheaves.

Comment: Well, using the definition of $\mathcal{G}_{P}$, wouldn't it simply mean that  we can restrict to some smaller open set $V \ni P$ in $U$, s.t. $\phi(U)$ is zero on that open set? And then we can pull that back to $\mathcal{F}(V)$ using the commutative diagram of morphisms of sheaves?

Comment: Right. $s|_V$ is a member of $(\ker \varphi)(V)$.